# Flutter Generic Api response

Tags: flutter, api, dart, http, flutter-web

**My app currently uses a custom class for each API response as a model. But I'm trying to change it to optimize some little things, so I'm trying to implement a class wrapper called ApiResponse for example. However, it doesn't work well with static calls and make fromJson and toJson methods.

Please help me out with converting the below JSON to a generic response where Items is going to be a Template class that can auto-map to any model, in dart.**

```
{
"result": {
    "totalCount": 3,
    "items": [
        {
            "vehicleUsedby": null,
            "from": "Malamulele ",
            "to": "Soshanguve ",
            "odoStart": "1234",
            "odoEnd": "1740",
            "personalMileage": "0",
            "businessMileage": "450",
            "distanceCovered": "450",
            "tollGate": "Diamond hill",
            "litersRefueled": "40",
            "amount": "900",
            "siteOrPlaceVisitedAndReason": "Auction",
            "type": {
                "item": "Personal",
                "itemValue": 1
            },
            "date": "2022-12-24T00:00:00",
            "id": "e2c0df8d-c752-43ba-938d-d5c8a2ecc058"
        },
        {
            "vehicleUsedby": null,
            "from": "Malamulele ",
            "to": "Soshanguve ",
            "odoStart": "1234",
            "odoEnd": "1740",
            "personalMileage": "0",
            "businessMileage": "450",
            "distanceCovered": "450",
            "tollGate": "Diamond hill",
            "litersRefueled": "40",
            "amount": "900",
            "siteOrPlaceVisitedAndReason": "Auction",
            "type": {
                "item": "Personal",
                "itemValue": 1
            },
            "date": "2022-12-24T00:00:00",
            "id": "d0c6b195-95d0-4f1a-b349-a68dba1f4d91"
        },
        {
            "vehicleUsedby": null,
            "from": "mat",
            "to": "jj",
            "odoStart": "",
            "odoEnd": "",
            "personalMileage": "",
            "businessMileage": "",
            "distanceCovered": "",
            "tollGate": "Diamond hill",
            "litersRefueled": "",
            "amount": "",
            "siteOrPlaceVisitedAndReason": "",
            "type": {
                "item": "Business",
                "itemValue": 2
            },
            "date": "2022-12-24T00:00:00",
            "id": "b60aace4-d513-458c-b7ee-28d1275bd75a"
        }
    ]
},
"targetUrl": null,
"success": true,
"error": null,
"unAuthorizedRequest": false,
"__abp": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this website to convert your JSON file to dart class as dataModel.
https://app.quicktype.io/

this website convert json to dart class by 2 methods( FROMJSON , TOMAP)

so . those methods can encoding and decoding your json and data model

Comment: That is fine it works but as you can check inside results there's a model called Items, that's the one i want to be made generic that I can pass any model, i can't be having more than one Items model for every api i call.